# why does dispatch does not fire in component

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have a search form component on a MERN stack app that takes a result from a option and a text input. Now if the user provides input it works like a charm. I tried to make a contingency for if the user clicks submit without any input with the following code:

```
const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(formData)
    if(formData.search === ""){
      console.log('fail')
      setError('search cannot be blank')
    } else { 
     setFilters(formData)
      getFilteredQuotes(formData, history)
     }
```

the console.log s both fire, but the setError dispatch does not. For other situations the setError works fine and has an onscreen display for a few seconds. However, the setError is done by dispatch(setError) in another action file rather than in the component file itself. Any ideas? If you need more code let me know.

Comment: if `setError` function is an `action`, then you need to call it with dispatch. You can have dispatch by using 
`const dispatch = useDispatch()` at the root level of your function component.
Then in your function `dispatch(setError('search cannot be blank'))`

Also, you might want to provide a stackblitz or a demo for people to help you better.

Comment: Yep That did it. Thank you very much. I had never heard of doing it that way. Also, I will look into stackblitz. Thank you.